# phantomjs: How to run phantomjs command when Url with queryparams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs

I am using Phantomjs to generate pdf from web page.
Using following command to generate pdf:

```
`phantomjs  rasterize.js http://www.myurl.com?q=123&&selected_opts%5B%5D=fs&selected_opts%5B%5D=disc form1.pdf`
```

where, selected_opts is array type

It is giving me error - form1.pdf: not found or selected_opts%5B%5D=fs: not found

If I remove querystring from url then it generate pdf, any idea how to run phantomjs having url with querystring.

Comment: You can try UrlEncoding the querystring part - `http://www.myurl.com?q%3D123%26s%3Dfoo`

Comment: Its not working form me. same error form1.pdf not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to protect all `&` chars with a backslash :

```
phantomjs  rasterize.js http://www.myurl.com?q=123\&s=foo form1.pdf
```

Ampersand is annoying in console so you need to protect it like above. In a ruby script you need to protect backslash that protect `&` :

```
`phantomjs  rasterize.js http://www.myurl.com?q=123\\&s=foo form1.pdf`
```

example :

```
`phantomjs rasterize.js https://www.google.fr/search?q=rasterize.js+special+char\\&oq=rasterize.js google1.pdf`
```

Comment: it gives me Unable to load the address! I have to send array in query params